# Поиск значения в json по первой букве и вывод результата

Tags: javascript, html, json

Как сделать поиск значение по "title" по первой букве, использую список алфавита ссылкой
На пример:

```html
<a href="#" id="letter">a</a>
<a href="#" id="letter">b</a>
<a href="#" id="letter">c</a>
<a href="#" id="letter">d</a>
...
```

И результат выводить на экран списком.

Имеется пример json:

```js
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 5,
    "products": [
    {
        "id": 203848165,
        "url": "/product/bottega-veneta",
        "title": "Bottega Veneta",
        "short_description": "мини-клатч The Pouch"
    },
    {
        "id": 203942281,
        "url": "/product/bugatti-tovarro",
        "title": "Bugatti Tovarro",
        "short_description": "моя личное название производителя"
    },
    {
        "id": 203848009,
        "url": "/product/fabio-bruno",
        "title": "Fabio Bruno",
        "short_description": "коньячная сумка-седло"
    },
    {
        "id": 203848011,
        "url": "/product/alex-santo",
        "title": "Alex Santo",
        "short_description": "коньячная alex-santo"
    },
    {
        "id": 203848022,
        "url": "/product/armani-tarasso",
        "title": "Armani Tarasso",
        "short_description": "лучшая armani-tarasso"
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
...
const letter = event.target.textContent.toUpperCase()
const filteredData = data.products.filter(product=>product.title.startsWith(letter))
...
```